# overwrite ng-bootstrap datepicker select.style

Tags: css, angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm using ng-bootstrap datepicker and having issue in select style month and year

[image]

the problem is in select style.

```
select[_ngcontent-c21] {
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding: 0 .5rem;    // the problem in this line
```

In Html, I have like this:

[image]

I think to solve this problem is to make **padding 0.0rem**

but I can not overwrite this style.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite every bootstrap style just by adding !important after value of style that u want to overwrite. 
 Example bootstrap styles overwriting:

```
.signup-form .btn:hover, .signup-form .btn:focus {
    background: #179b81 !important;
}
```

In your case try:

```
select[_ngcontent-c21] {
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding: 0 rem !important; 
}
```

Comment: the problem that [_nghost-c21] > select[_ngcontent-c21]

is generated automatically meaning in other test it can be

[_nghost-c24] > select[_ngcontent-c24]    so the overwrite should be in other place

Answer (score 0):

add
`encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,`
in your component(where you are using the datepicker) metadata .

```
@Component({
  selector: 'wrapper-date-picker',
  templateUrl: './date-picker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./date-picker.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

this is not just for datepicker, this helps you to overwrite any component from any 3rd party lib styles similar to ng-bootstrap.